# How can I implement a Javascript when it´s only built for a special viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, viewport

I have the following HTML below that shows a list.

HTML:

```
<div id="Footer">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#" title="AGB">AGB</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="Impressum">Impressum</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="Datenschutz">Datenschutz</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="Copyrightbestimmungen">Copyrightbestimmungen</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

With the following JavaScript I want to sort out one list-point. It´s necessary because the footer has to be minimized for the viewport of mobile devices.

JavaScript:

```
var t = document.querySelectorAll('a[title=Datenschutz]');
t[0].parentNode.style.display = "none";
```

**Now I want to expand the function so, that it takes when mobile devices are used or rather the viewport/ max-device-width is under 1024px. (see below). 
Over this size the JavaScript function from above should be ignored!**

My Media Queries in CSS are named

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 767px) and (orientation: portrait)
```

and

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since doing and ignoring `JS` is your priority, doing so by js itself would be my suggestion!!

```
var width = window.innerWidth;
if(width >= 1024)
{
   /* do js for device width greater than 1024px */
} 
else
{
   /* do js for device width less than 1024px */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this [`window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia):

```
window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 960px)")
```

[Polyfill](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/) from Paul Irish.

Comment: You could add a usage sample.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the lines to

```
...
<li class="datenschutz"><a href="#">Datenschutz</a></li>
...
```

Remove the javascript and do all the logic in the media queries

e.g.

```
...
#Footer .datenschutz { display: none; }
...
```

Though using ID selectors in css is not optimal (solution: change ID on footer div to class if not needed in js etc.).

Comment: That´s the problem! I have no access to change the html therefore I tried it via JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, I maybe formulated unclearly. There exists a main/content html file of an extern server where I cannot access in. On the client site I have a user interface to expand the file (HTML, CSS). that´s it while I have to use JavaSript.